# JsPDF - Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, electron, jspdf

I wrote this simple code for test the `jsPDF` library:

```
const base64Img = require('base64-img');
const JsPDF     = require('jspdf');

const LAYOUT    = base64Img.base64Sync('img/layout.png');    

$('#esporta').click( () => {
    var pdf = new JsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(LAYOUT, 'PNG', 18.25, 19.25, 190, 255);
    pdf.save('test.pdf');
});
```

I have a simple button that when it clicked the pdf should be generated; but I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
>       at new e (/Users/th3g3ntl3man/Repository/thermowell-design/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js:269)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.$.click (export.js:62)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

The line `export.js:62` is the creation of the pdf: `var pdf = new JsPDF();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reported issue. You can see [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2176).
By the time I type this message. The fix patch has not been merged yet. You can use the zip file attached [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2176#issuecomment-450034947) temporarily and wait for next official version released.

Extract the zip file, and copy them to node_modules/jspdf/dist, overwrite the original four files, and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Today we released 1.5.3. This should fix your issue.